# More complex flow type refinement on switch statements

Tags: javascript, types, flowtype

Assume that I have a code like this, where I have 2 object types, and I am trying to leverage refinement on a switch statement that would support more complex cases

```
/* @flow */

type Add = {
 type: "add",
 someAddSpecificStuff: 3,
};

type Sub = {
 type: "sub",
};

type Actions =
  | Add
  | Sub;

function reducer(model: number = 0, action: Actions): number {  
  switch(true) {
    case action.type === "add":
      return model + 1 + action.someAddSpecificStuff;
    case action.type === "sub":
      return model - 1;
    default:
      return model;
  }
}
```

This gives me:

> 27:         return model + 1 + action.addSpecific;
>                                         ^ property `addSpecific`. Property not found in
>
> 27:         return model + 1 + action.addSpecific;
>                                  ^ object type

Whereas if I do as follows obviously works:

```
switch (action.type) {
  case "add":
  ...
```

The reason I am triying to use the above pattern is to be able to *catch all* types stored on an array for example and re-use that catch-all functionality, for example:

```
switch(true) {
  case BIG_ARRAY_OF_OBJECT_TYPES.includes(action.type) {
    return action.somethingIKnowThatIsAlwaysPresentInTheseActions;
  }
}
```

How is the way this kind of thing is normally done?

Comment: Could certainly be a Flow bug. That said, it seems like for readability you'd be better off making this an `if/else` at this point.

Comment: What version of JS is that? Asking as `case` expects const expression but in your case that's not so.